# Erlang distributed message sending - what is the meaning of the first atom in the tuple?

Tags: erlang

The Erlang [User's Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#send) describes the [send operator](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#send) as

> #### 8.9  Send
>
> ```
> Expr1 ! Expr2
> ```
>
> Sends the value of `Expr2` as a message to the process specified by
>   `Expr1`. The value of `Expr2` is also the return value of the
>   expression.
>
> `Expr1` must evaluate to a **pid**, a **registered name** (atom), or a **tuple
>   `{Name,Node}`**. `Name` is an atom and `Node` is a node name, also an
>   atom.
>
> - If `Expr1` evaluates to a name, but this name is not registered, a `badarg` run-time error occurs.
> - Sending a message to a pid never fails, even if the pid identifies a    non-existing process.
> - Distributed message sending, that is, if `Expr1` evaluates to a tuple    `{Name,Node}` (or a pid located at another node), also never
>     fails.

In the case of distributed message sending, it is not clear to me what the first atom represents in `{Name,Node}` from the code of the remote node or process.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grammar is a bit ambiguous in the sentence you're citing.  The three options are:

- A process ID, which is an opaque data type returned from certain Erlang functions, primarily spawn and spawn_link.
- A registered name on the local node (i.e., the local VM). An example of where this would be needed would be a long-running server application, where you want processes to be able to communicate with a key utility service, such as a DNS cache.
- A tuple containing both a registered name and the name of the node it lives on (if another VM, potentially on a different host).

The first is by far the most common.  Registered names are intended to be used judiciously.

I'd recommend starting with the concurrency chapter from Learn You Some Erlang, and backtracking as necessary to earlier chapters:
http://learnyousomeerlang.com/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-concurrency#dont-panic

Answer (score 3):

let's say you have two nodes: node1@localhost and node2@localhost and you register an erlang process in node1 as process1.

You can send messages from node2 to process1 in node1 as:

```
{process1, node1@localhost} ! yourmessage.
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

In this expression:

> Expr1 ! Expr2

**Expr1** must evaluate to (1) **a pid**, (2) **a registered name (atom)** or (3) **a tuple {Name,Node}**.

In the 3rd case, as you wanted to know, when Expr1 evaluates to a **tuple {Name, Node}**, Name is a registered name (atom) of a process and Node is a node name (also an atom) like *name@server*.

For example:

```
% ------- in your node -------
(you@server)> register(shell, self()).

% ------- in my node -------
(me@server)> {shell, you@server} ! "hey you!".
```

Note that before sending message to other processes in other nodes, first you have to connect to them. For example with **spawn(Node, Module, Function, Arguments)** or **net_adm:ping(Node)**.

For testing purpose use **nodes()** function to list connected nodes.